# React not render class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, components, render

I use client-side routes(HashRouter, Link). In App component i have 3 components - Home, Page1, Page2. And i want to get data from server and on Page1 display this data dynamicaly. But when i go to this page i have error:
[image]

When i don't configure Page1 as class and configure it such as const (just as in app.jsx Home component) all work fine, but when i try to configure it like a class, i get this error which i described below.

Here my code:

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { 
  Container, 
  Row, 
  Col 
} from 'react-grid-system';
import Page1 from "./page1.jsx";

const Home = () => (
  <div class="container-fixed">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-l-4">
        <h2 class="underline">Home</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

const Subpage = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

const Page2 = ({ match }) => (
  <div class="container-fixed">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-l-4">
        <h2 class="underline">Subpages</h2>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-item">
            <Link to={`${match.url}/subpage1`}>
              subpage1
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li class="content-list-item">
            <Link to={`${match.url}/subpage2`}>
            subpage2
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li class="content-list-item">
            <Link to={`${match.url}/subpage3`}>
            subpage3
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Subpage}/>
        <Route exact path={match.path} render={() => (
          <h3>Please select a subpage.</h3>
        )}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
      <Router>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col md={2}>
              <h2 class="underline">Menu</h2>
              <ul class="content-list">
                <li class="content-list-item">
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li class="content-list-item">
                  <Link to="/page1">Page1</Link>
                </li>
                <li class="content-list-item">
                  <Link to="/page2">Page2</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
              <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Router>  
)

export default App
```

page1.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const Row_ = function(props){
    const {id, content} = props;
    return (
      <div>
        id: {id}
        content: {content}
      </div>
    );
  }

  class Page1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        datas: [
          {id: 14, content: "test"},
          {id: 25, content: "test2"},
          {id: 75, content: "test3"},
        ]
      };
    }

    handleClick() {
      let fetchedData = gerData();
      this.addDataToHTML(fetchedData.id, fetchedData.content);
    }

    getData() {
      fetch('/testdata', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
    }

    addDataToHTML(id, content){    
      const datas = [...this.state.datas, 
                    {value: id, checked: content}
                   ];
      this.setState({
          datas,
      });
    }

    render(){
      <div class="container-fixed">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-l-4">
            <h2 class="underline">Page11</h2>
            {this.state.datas.map((row, idx) => {
            return(
                <Row_ 
                    id={row.id}
                    content={row.content}
                    /> 
                )
            })
            }
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Get data
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
  }

  export default Page1
```

index.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from "./app.jsx";
import "../t_styles/css/components.min.css";
import "../t_styles/js/components.min.js";
import $ from "jquery";

ReactDOM.render((
  <App></App>
), document.getElementById('index'))
```

Comment: A minified React error doesn't say much, sadly. Could you try this again without minifying your code and post that error in the question instead? And when do you get this error?

Comment: @Tholle how can i turn off minimize a JS-code?

Comment: @SeBr use className instead of class.

Comment: @javed thnx, i fix it, but another error: [link](https://ibb.co/eNzxz8)

Comment: @SeBr add return statement in you components return method. check post i given.

Comment: @javed yep, it's work! thnx!)

Comment: @SeBr cool.....!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. use className instead of class.
2. add return statement in your render method of Page1 component

    render(){
      return (<div className="container-fixed">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-l-4">
            <h2 className="underline">Page11</h2>
            {this.state.datas.map((row, idx) => {
            return(
                <Row_ 
                    id={row.id}
                    content={row.content}
                    /> 
                )
            })
            }
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Get data
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't see the actual errors, my guess is that your handlers are not bound to the `class` instance, and therefore you can't access it via `this`.

So Either bind them to the `class` (this usually done inside the `constructor`):

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.getData= this.getData.bind(this);
this.addDataToHTML= this.addDataToHTML.bind(this);
```

Or use an arrow function syntax that will use `this` in a lexical context:

```
handleClick = () => {
  let fetchedData = gerData();
  this.addDataToHTML(fetchedData.id, fetchedData.content);
}
```

Comment: i try to do this, but first way don't solve problem, second way have error - syntax is wrong in `handleClick = () => {` first `=` is Unexpected token

Comment: the second way required a babel plugin ["plugin-transform-class-properties"](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) but if the first way doesn't solve the problem then it is not the problem anyway. Though i don't see a way for your code to work properly without the fix i posted.

Comment: I delete all methods (handleClick, getData, addDataToHTML) and error hangs so far. Maybe it's problem with routes or in constructor of class? Because if i configure Page1 as const all works fine